# Implement both Iterator and ResultSet interface in a single class - Conflict

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

I have a scenario where a single class needs to implement both Iterator and ResultSet interface.

Code looks like this

[image]

Error also is shown above.

Can you suggest if there is any alternative to this issue?

Comment: How about...Not implementing both `ResultSet` and `Iterable`?

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for the suggestion. But that is NOT what I asked for

Comment: ...Then I'm not sure what you want.  The compiler is telling you that both `Iterator` and `ResultSet` implement the `next()` method, and they are incompatible between one another.  The compiler *literally* cannot tell which `next` method you would mean if you invoked `(SubclassOfMyClass).next()`.  You have to choose - is this implementing `ResultSet`, or is this implementing `Iterable`?

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I understand. Thanks for the detailed explanation of why it cannot. So does it mean there is no work around and I should remove one interface?

Comment: I don't really know why you are trying to do that, but the only way to do that is create a intermediary classes that each one implements Iterator and ResultSet and instantiate those classes into your abstract class. As explained before, the compiler will not allow to have two implementations with the same signature with different return types, because it is interpreted as duplicated method by the compiler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting that error because both Resultset and Iterable have method next() in them, but have a different returns value

resultset next has boolean as return value
Iterator next has E as return value

but the calling signature is the same. In java, you do not get polymorphism by changing only the return value; this has resulted in compiler error.

instead of inheritance you can go for composition include Resultset within class as instance variable.

```
public class MyClass<E> implements Iterator<E>, Iterable<E>{
    private ResultSet resultset;
}
```